# Ignore later patterns in python regex if previous patterns are not found

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dicom

How do I match a series of groups but later groups should only match if all previous groups matched?

Example:

Match any string up to "abc" with each character in its own group.

Valid: a, ab, abc
Invalid: b, c, bc, ac

The following works, but I'm not sure if there's a better way:

```
^(a)?(?(1)(b)?)(?(2)(c)?)$
```

That says that each match is optional, but depends on the group before it matching. That is, 'c' cannot match unless 'b' matches which cannot happen unless 'a' matches.

To help anyone googling this later, I'm parsing a [Dicom DateTime](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_6.2.html#para_89d6d588-e108-4ee1-b4ba-74a5c3f0df43) which has the following format.

```
 YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.FFFFFF&ZZXX     # &ZZXX is an optional timezone offset
```

I used code to build this regex rather than just typing it in like this.

```
dicom_dt_parser = re.compile(
    r'^' +
    r'(?P<year>\d{4})' +
    r'(?(year)(?P<month>\d{2})?)' +
    r'(?(month)(?P<day>\d{2})?)' +
    r'(?(day)(?P<hour>\d{2})?)' +
    r'(?(hour)(?P<min>\d{2})?)' +
    r'(?(min)(?P<sec>\d{2})?)' +
    r'(?(sec)(?P<frac>\.\d{1,6})?)' +
    r'(?P<tz>[\+\-]\d{4})?' +
    r'$'
)
```

`dicom_dt_parser.match(datetime_string).groupdict()` will return a dictionary with all of the fields. Missing fields will have values of `None`.

Comment: What's wrong with pydicom [TM class](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/blob/master/pydicom/valuerep.py#L222) ?

Comment: @malat I didn't know about it. We have our own c++ library that we've used in all of our products. I was wrapping that.

Comment: Oh, that project could be useful. It's incomplete as it only operates on the files, but I can still use some of the features like the TM class.

Comment: This is still not clear why your c++ library is not doing the call to `strptime` already. In which case you would simply need to wrap `struct tm` to python, which I bet is standardized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly fine, readable and straightforward. This is another shorter way to build your regex as well, using nested groups:

```
^a(b(c)?)?$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tq0YPj/1)

If you are going to accept empty input strings you may want to append `|^$` to above regex.

Regex for `abcdef` would be:

```
^a(b(c(d(e(f)?)?)?)?)?$
```

Your regex built with this work around:

```
^(?P<year>\d{4})(?:(?P<month>\d{2})(?:(?P<day>\d{2})(?:(?P<hour>\d{2})(?:(?P<min>\d{2})(?:(?P<sec>\d{2})(?:(?P<frac>\.\d{1,6})(?P<tz>[+-]\d{4})?)?)?)?)?)?)?$
```

Your own regex:

```
^(?P<year>\d{4})(?(year)(?P<month>\d{2})?)(?(month)(?P<day>\d{2})?)(?(day)(?P<hour>\d{2})?)(?(hour)(?P<min>\d{2})?)(?(min)(?P<sec>\d{2})?)(?(sec)(?P<frac>\.\d{1,6})?)(?P<tz>[\+\-]\d{4})?$
```

Comment: I like this, but I needed to capture each part in it's own group. I'm parsing a Date & Time format that can omit fields from right to left. So, something like YYYYmmddHHMMSS.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. What are you going to do after matching expected substrings?

Comment: I'm parsing a timestamp from a string format into an actual datetime object.

Comment: I built your regex with this solution and tried to add corresponding groups to it. A bit shorter if you check. @Harvey

Comment: Cool, it removes the need to keep track of the previous group number or name. Minor correction, the timezone is always optional regardless of what comes before: `^(?P<year>\d{4})(?:(?P<month>\d{2})(?:(?P<day>\d{2})(?:(?P<hour>\d{2})(?:(?P<min>\d{2})(?:(?P<sec>\d{2})(?:(?P<frac>\.\d{1,6}))?)?)?)?)?)?(?P<tz>[+-]\d{4})?$`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go for so many backreferences, a simple non-capturing group and an OR condition should be more than enough for the use case:

```
^(a)(?:(b)(c)|(b))?$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UPEY2w/1)

Comment: I have 8 groups. I think this would get really messy repeating patterns.